# How to set background color in grid based on condition in action script file

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

I have a gird data, and want to set bg color of the grid row based on condition means if there is flag =1 then background grid row will be showing in grey color otherwise as it is in action script file. I used blazeds service.

please help me out. I already tried to setStyle(), but not got success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an actionscript 3 solution.
You need to do it in a special itemRenderer class.
I suggest you extend the Label class and in it override the updateDisplayList function.

```
public class DynamicItemRenderer extends Label
{
    private var _backgroundColorFunction:Function=null;

    override protected function commitProperties():void
    {
        super.commitProperties();
        var cellBackgroundColor:Boolean=this.document.hasOwnProperty("cellColorFunction");
        if (cellBackgroundColor && _backgroundColorFunction == null)
        {
            _backgroundColorFunction=this.document.cellColorFunction as Function;
        }
    }

    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        if (_backgroundColorFunction != null)
        {
            _backgroundColorFunction.call(this, data, graphics, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the mxml file, where your DataGrid is defined, you need to set up a function that will color the cell, which will be your backgroundColorFunction.

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public function cellColorFunction(... args):void
        {
            var item:Object=args[0];
            var g:Graphics=args[1] as Graphics;
            var width:Number=args[2] as Number;
            var height:Number=args[3] as Number;

            g.clear();
            if (grid.isItemSelected(item) || grid.isItemHighlighted(item))
                return;
            if (item.flag == 1)
            {
                g.beginFill(0xE2E2E2);
                g.drawRect(0, 0, width, height + 4);
                g.endFill();
            }
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

Then you need to define the item renderer on your gridColumn and that's it.

```
<mx:DataGridColumn itemRenderer="path.to.your.DynamicItemRenderer"/>
```

This is the best solution that I have come up with.
If anyone knows a better way I'd like to see it :)

Comment: I am using custom datagrid, so it will work on it also?      <controls:MDataGrid x="3" y="15" id="gd1" allowMultipleSelection="true" color="blue" width="97.5%" horizontalScrollPolicy="on" verticalScrollPolicy="on" height="130">  
<controls:columns>
<dataGridClasses:MDataGridColumn headerText="Execution Id" dataField="execId" width="160"/> </controls:columns>
</controls:MDataGrid>

Comment: @anshul If your MDataGridColumn class extends DataGridColumn then it should be fine.

Comment: :I made DynamicItemRenderer.as class file and put ur method and import this file into mxml file. when i used this code <dataGridClasses:MDataGridColumn headerText="Exception" dataField="flag" itemRenderer="DynamicItemRenderer"/>, it is giving an error "Functionality DynamicItemRenderer could not be found". I also tried by using this path <dataGridClasses:MDataGridColumn headerText="Exception" dataField="flag" itemRenderer="com.headstrong.teevra.utils.DynamicItemRenderer"/>,but it failed with same error.Please suggest or is there any simple solution to color the grid row.I am new in Flex.

Comment: This:
<dataGridClasses:MDataGridColumn headerText="Exception" dataField="flag" itemRenderer="com.headstrong.teevra.utils.DynamicItemRenderer"/>

looks like the correct solution.
Please check your build path, is the renderer class included in the build?
Or please post more information.

Comment: Thanks Franz, it worked now. one thing it colored only that particular cell i.e. "Exception" one while I want to color whole row, so what i did, i used  itemRenderer="com.headstrong.teevra.utils.DynamicItemRenderer" property in each column. Is this correct way, or should i change something in method. Thank you once again.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct solution.
Each column should have the same renderrer.
This is a cleaner solution than overriding DataGrid's drawRowBackground method, because that would mean you can only use that grid in one specific case.
Glad it worked :)